# Apache Flink 1.14 - StreamingFileSink not copying all files to S3

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-s3, apache-flink, amazon-eks, flink-streaming

`StreamingFileSink` is not copying all files to S3. It begins correctly by copying files until the file count equals parallelism, and then it stops copying. I have tried `FileSink` too, but I got the same result. I am doing this on EKS. I see this in the logs:

```
org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.writer.S3Committer [] - Trying to commit after recovery
```

We are upgrading from `Flink 1.9` to `Flink 1.14`. Code worked in Flink 1.9. The only change we made in the code was to replace the `ContinuousFileReaderOperator` with `ContinuousFileReaderOperatorFactory`

```
DataStreamSink<Tuple3<String, String, String>> output = env.addSource(fileSource)
.transform("FileSplitReader", typeInfo, new ContinuousFileReaderOperator<>(inputFormat))
            .map(...)
            .flatMap(...)
            .filter(...).addSink(s3Sink);
```

Replaced with

```
DataStreamSink<Tuple3<String, String, String>> output = env.addSource(fileSource)
.transform("FileSplitReader", typeInfo, new ContinuousFileReaderOperatorFactory<>(inputFormat))
            .map(...)
            .flatMap(...)
            .filter(...).addSink(s3Sink);
```

Sink code is the same:

```
StreamingFileSink<?> s3Sink = StreamingFileSink
            .forRowFormat(new Path(s3BucketPath), ...)
            .withBucketAssigner(...)
            .withRollingPolicy(...)
            .withBucketCheckInterval(...)
            .build();
```

Screenshot from the Flink dashboard

[image]

Any pointers on why this is happening?

Comment: There's a couple of recommendations: 1) Flink 1.14 is already out of support, so I would recommend upgrading to Flink 1.16 2) The StreamingFileSink is deprecated and replaced by FileSink, which I don't see 3) You're not using the FileSource as the source. See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/connectors/datastream/filesystem/ for all details on the FileSource and FileSink connector for the DataStream API.

Comment: @MartijnVisser Thanks Martijin. I have already tried FileSink. It has the same issue. Could you please share if you have any examples of how to use FileSource?